# How to insert Data in ACF field in WordPress on DB

Tags: mysql, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I created an ACF field for the user profile.

I want to insert data into an ACF Field on database level. I added two lines in the user_meta One for the group I want for the field. But on the user profile The field is empty.

Background: there is a value for every user from a separate system. I like to update every user with the specific value. My idea was to update the ACF on DB level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally follow your situation, but by the sound of it, you are looking for...

```
update_field("field_name or field_id", "user_".$user_id);
```

[Source](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/)